# Can there be DNS records for subdomains but not for the main domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

Is it possible to have DNS records for `mail.example.com` and `dav.example.com` but not for `example.com`?

There is nothing served on `example.com`. It only contains a MX record.

Why I need this: I use Apache to vhost `mail.example.com` and `dav.example.com` using the same IP. There is no site on `example.com`. If a user enters `https://example.com` Apache servers the first enabled vhost that supports SSL/TLS which is `dav.example.com`. The user gets a certificate error because of domain (CN) mismatch. Afaik I can't solve this inside Apache because SSL negotiation happens before the `HOST` HTTP-Header is send. So I thought I might solve this on the DNS level.

Comment: Are you sure you want nothing on the main domain? You could set it to 127.0.0.1, but for usability purposes it could be viable to provide users with links to your applications/subdomains

Comment: Yes, I only use it for mail, webmail (mail.) and dav resources (dav.).

Comment: If you have an SSL cert for `www.example.com` they will _sometimes_ have added `example.com` as a subject alternate name for free. Check your certs carefully, and perhaps get this added.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the "A" record for example.com. You don't need to mess with the structure of the domain itself. It's fine to have a zone called example.com and a sub zone called mail.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as your DNS system supports it.

If you would want to server `example.com` you would need another record, which is typically prompted as `@` record.

So if you don't want to server on `example.com` but on those subdomains, simply just add the subdomains to your system.